# Glusterfs: rpc actor failed to complete successfully

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, glusterfs

I have `glusterfs` service running over CentOS 6, an I can see those errors filling up the logs continuously:

```
[2021-03-09 07:13:52.692995] E [rpcsvc.c:450:rpcsvc_check_and_reply_error] 0-rpcsvc: rpc actor failed to complete successfully
[2021-03-09 07:13:52.695872] E [rpcsvc.c:195:rpcsvc_program_actor] 0-rpc-service: RPC Program procedure not available for procedure 2 in GF-DUMP
[2021-03-09 07:13:52.695924] E [rpcsvc.c:450:rpcsvc_check_and_reply_error] 0-rpcsvc: rpc actor failed to complete successfully
[2021-03-09 07:13:52.697951] E [rpcsvc.c:195:rpcsvc_program_actor] 0-rpc-service: RPC Program procedure not available for procedure 2 in GF-DUMP
[2021-03-09 07:13:52.697990] E [rpcsvc.c:450:rpcsvc_check_and_reply_error] 0-rpcsvc: rpc actor failed to complete successfully
[2021-03-09 07:13:52.702147] E [rpcsvc.c:195:rpcsvc_program_actor] 0-rpc-service: RPC Program procedure not available for procedure 2 in GF-DUMP
[2021-03-09 07:13:52.702199] E [rpcsvc.c:450:rpcsvc_check_and_reply_error] 0-rpcsvc: rpc actor failed to complete successfully
[2021-03-09 07:13:52.709498] E [rpcsvc.c:195:rpcsvc_program_actor] 0-rpc-service: RPC Program procedure not available for procedure 2 in GF-DUMP
[2021-03-09 07:13:52.709538] E [rpcsvc.c:450:rpcsvc_check_and_reply_error] 0-rpcsvc: rpc actor failed to complete successfully
[2021-03-09 07:13:52.709604] E [rpcsvc.c:195:rpcsvc_program_actor] 0-rpc-service: RPC Program procedure not available for procedure 2 in GF-DUMP
[2021-03-09 07:13:52.709624] E [rpcsvc.c:450:rpcsvc_check_and_reply_error] 0-rpcsvc: rpc actor failed to complete successfully
```

I am pretty sure it is not `gluster` by itself, however, I am trying to figure out what is the exact root cause of this.

Comment: Warning: CentOS 6 is past end of life. It may not be possible to answer this question at all. You are strongly encouraged to update to a currently supported Linux distribution before November 2020. That is not a typo.

Comment: @MichaelHampton This is well known issue, however, am pretty sure this something else rather than the kernel itself. I am looking for quick solution that can be achieved before migration project to next OS version.